# JavaFX 2.0 custom Window frame buttons

Tags: window, frame, javafx

I want to add a button to my applications window frame. At the moment I have the regular windows look: "minimize, maximize and close". I were thinking that I should make a whole new window frame with my own buttons, but what I really need is just an additional button that has the functionality of "Log out". Kinda like Skype: http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Compact-View.jpg

I have been searching the web for some pointers and hints, but I've gotten no longer.

So if anybody has any comments or code that would help me, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The JavaFX Ensemble Sample application demonstrates custom buttons for "minimize, maximize and close", you can get it's source code [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html).